# How many known distance-20 positions are found so far for the Rubik's cube in half-turn metrics?

Tags: rubiks-cube

This [site](http://www.cube20.org/distance20s/) says: "All 93,659,370 known distance-20 positions as of 18 March 2014 are available below." And in total there are about 490 millions of them.
This information is 3 years old. Does anybody have some new info about this? And some new estimate, how many distance-20 positions are there in total? Is there a list of these positions available (besides the one on the cube20.org site)?

Comment: Since it was proven that all positions on the cube are solvable in 20 or fewer moves, are you asking for positions which require exactly 20 moves?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: I see someone has voted to close this as off-topic. I suggest that this is very decidedly *not* off-topic: it is not a puzzle, but it is a question *about* a puzzle, and those are absolutely fine. (In the earliest days of puzzling.se, the debate was about whether actual puzzle questions were on topic or whether the site was only meant to be used for questions about puzzles!)

Comment: I initially flagged as off topic because of the "this seems outdated", "is there new info" which seemed very speculative. "Is there a list available", also speculating that there is new information out there.

Comment: "it seems outdated" is just a wording. It is obvious, based on the date 2014, that it is outdated.

Comment: The relevance of the question lies in part in this phrase from the linked site:" I am finding new distance-20 positoins at a rate of about 200,000 per day; I may update these files and numbers as time permits. ". But no update appears to be given. If said ratio continued, the list could indeed be significantly larger.. 73 million a year, times 3 years and some, means there could potentially be a 300 million+ list...  (if the upper bound isn't reached beforehand obviously)